# 'Could not load type' error when viewing a web app package on IIS

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2012

I am new to Visual Studio 2012 and the Web Deploy 3.0 used to upload a package to IIS. While my application compiles and renders fine on my local development laptop, when I package the web app and then import the packaged zip file to my site on IIS I get error when I try to view the page. When I open IE on my local machine and browse to my site address by IP (_http://1.2.3.4/acme/tools/default.aspx) I get this error "Server Error in '/' Application." and then further below "Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'ACME.Default'". The source error is pointing to my page declaration. It appears that it is having trouble with the 'Inherits="ACME.Default"' , but why? And how to fix?

Many thanks.
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your AppPool version versus your app -- typical IIS configurations will still default to 2.0 not 4.0 and this is exactly the sort of error one sees when one has that kind of version mismatch.

Comment: When I go into my site under IIS and click "View Applications" there is listed under the Virtual Path "Tools" and under Site "ACME" and under Application Pool "ASP.Net v4.0". If I go under my site and click "Advanced Settings" I see my Application Pool is "ASP.Net v4.0". When I go to my Application Pools I can see the "ASP.Net v4.0" which is set to v4.0 Framework and has an "Integrated" Pipeline with an Identity of "ApplicationPoolIdentity". Does this help?

Comment: Yes -- is your app 4.0 or is it 2.0 or 3.5 (which is really 2.0++)?

Comment: Has anyone installed 4.5 on the server? 4.5 runs as a 4.0 app pool but it expects the 4.5 in-place "upgrade" to be installed.

Comment: I ran the installer yesterday just to make sure it was installed. The installer was "dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.exe". It installed without errors. Does the v4.5 also run under the version v4.0.30319?

Comment: As far as I know yes but I can't claim to have any deployed 4.5 apps yet. Now, I don't think this is your problem. Other dumb question -- did you deploy the /bin folder here? That is the other likely cause of this sort of thing.

Comment: I imported my packaged .zip file which created the "tools" sub-directory under my parent web site and added the "bin", "content", ACME.dbml, default.aspx, and web.config. The content folder is my CSS, JS, and images.

Comment: I did a test to see if the .Net framework v4.5 was causing the issue so I downgraded to v4.0 and recompiled my app. I moved it over to the IIS server but I still get the same error. Ugh.

Comment: Sorry, you might want to post the entire exception so someone can help pull out the underlying reason -- it sounds like there is an underlying dependency which can't load but I've already shot in the dark and missed twice so I'll save the next bullet . . .

Comment: I opened a ticket with Microsoft and found some answers. There were incorrect configurations in my publishing process. After we fixed these issues the problem was fixed. When using the "Web Deploy 3.0" packaging interface, here were the steps I used:
1. Publish method = Web Deploy
2. Server = _https://servername:8172/msdeploy.axd
3. Site Name = Default Web Site/mysitename

(remove the _ underscore in the server https:)
The port number was provided by the Microsoft tech. It is a standard port for publishing. 
I hope this helps someone else.